# NoClassDefFoundError: com/aventstack/extentreports/reporter/ExtentHtmlReporter

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, extentreports

I am trying to obtain a report in my `maven` project using `Cucumber`, and `ExtentReport`. I am using **java 8**. Here are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vimalselvam/cucumber-extentsreport -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

and then i used the below runner class, to run all my `*.feature` files:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features            = {"src/test/resources/features" }, 
        monochrome          = true,
        plugin              = {"com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:output/report.html"},
        glue                = {"stepDefinitions"}
        )
public class TestRunnerJUnit {


}
```

But when i run the test-Runner, it complains with:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/aventstack/extentreports/reporter/ExtentHtmlReporter
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.instantiate(PluginFactory.java:114)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.create(PluginFactory.java:87)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.getPlugins(RuntimeOptions.java:245)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions$1.invoke(RuntimeOptions.java:291)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.done(Unknown Source)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.done(JUnitReporter.java:227)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/aventstack/extentreports/reporter/ExtentHtmlReporter
    at com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter.setExtentHtmlReport(ExtentCucumberFormatter.java:55)
    at com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter.<init>(ExtentCucumberFormatter.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.instantiate(PluginFactory.java:107)
    ... 12 more
```

---

***Update:***

When i add the below dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I receive this new error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: testName cannot be null or empty
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest.<init>(ExtentTest.java:80)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports.createTest(ExtentReports.java:105)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports.createTest(ExtentReports.java:145)
    at com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter.feature(ExtentCucumberFormatter.java:155)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions$1.invoke(RuntimeOptions.java:294)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.feature(Unknown Source)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.feature(JUnitReporter.java:184)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:69)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. 
Everything was fine, but i needed to added a value to `Feature` in the  `*.feature` file.
So, here you can see the **`Feature`** key word should exist, and ***exactly*** in front of it should be a text. If you write the text in next line, you will face with the error.

```
Feature: Check Welcome-message
  As a user, I should find a welcome-message in my mailbox, and my age in my profile.
```

Answer (score 2):

try to replace this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

with this one

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

the component "cucumber-extentsreport" and "extentreports" are different things.
I had the same issue and solved by using "extentreports" version 3.0.7 with "cucumber-extentsreport" version 3.1.1
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Everything was fine, but i needed to added a value to Feature in the *.feature file. So, here you can see the Feature key word should exist, and exactly in front of it should be a text. If you write the text in next line, you will face with the error.  :- Yes its work for me too